# Why I can't find the serverside code for the button?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a web application got from my client to do some changes on it. Here, is one button named Submit. If user clicks this button then it check on database and get the result but I can't find the code for this button. I need to change the query but I cannot find the source.
Here is the aspx code:

```
   <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-info" ValidationGroup="submit" />
```

But if I inspect element using firefox then I can see this:

```
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("Submit", "", true, "submit", "", false, false))" id="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
```

I don't understand where does this onclick function comes from and how it works with the SQL query.I cannot find any click event into the .cs file as well. Please advise me on this.

Comment: Check any Javascript on the page or external Javascript files.

Comment: Buttons do not have to be wired up to a click handler to cause a postback. So you should look within the normal page life cycle events like Page_Init and Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

Check PostBackUrl property for the Button server control.

Answer (score 0):

Put at the onClick="Submit" in ur button field like
  
then on code behind the click event method will be shown and do your code